# How to group phone number with and without country code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to detect phone number, my country code is `+62` but some phone manufacturer or operator use `0` and `+62`, after query and pivoting I get pivoted data. But, the pivoted data is out of context

Here's the pivoted data

```
Id    +623684682   03684682   +623684684   03684684
1              1          0            1          1
2              1          1            2          1
```

Here's what I need to group, but I don't want to group manually (`+623684682` and `03684682` is same, etc)

```
Id      03684682   03684684
1              1          2
2              2          3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think need `replace` with aggregate `sum`:

```
df = df.groupby(lambda x: x.replace('+62','0'), axis=1).sum()
```

Or [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) columns names and `sum`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('\+62','0')
df = df.sum(level=0, axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
    03684682  03684684
Id                    
1          1         2
2          2         3
```

Comment: can you make the code if the pivot is done by someone else, I don have access to raw data

Comment: @NabihBawazir - `if the pivot is done by someone else`, can you explain more?